# idiomatic path for leiningen test data

Tags: testing, clojure, leiningen

*By convention*, where is data accompanying test typically stored in Leiningen projects?

Some possibilities include:
`<project_name>/test/<project_name>/data/`, `<project_name>/test/<project_name>/`, or
`<project_name>/test/data/`.

Please list sources of information or reasons behind your argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of directory structure:

- With "src/main-style" directory tree, where your main Clojure source lives under `src/main/clojure` and your tests under `src/test/clojure`, I would place test data under `src/test/resources`.
- With "src-style" directory tree, where your main Clojure source lives under `src` and your tests under `test`, I would place test data under `dev-resources` or `test-resources`.

In either case, I would add the appropriate resources directory to `:resources` for the `:dev` and/or `:test` profiles (except `"dev-resources"` is actually the default path, so nothing needs to be added if you go with it):

```
(defproject … …
  :profiles {:dev {:resources ["src/test/resources"]
                   … …}
             … …}
  … …)
```

Comment: Thank you, @michal marczyk. Do you know if this style is conventional or does it just feel right?

Comment: Additionally, do you mind explaining the modifications to `project.clj` in more detail?

Comment: It is conventional – the "src-style" approach with `dev-resources` is Leiningen's default, and "src/main-style" with appropriately placed `resources` directories is standard in the JVM world. As for `project.clj`, the `:profiles` key occurs at top level; below that, if you just add what's there in the answer, omitting the `…`s, `src/test/resources` should be available in `:dev` profile.